# codeigniter ion-auth2 redirects me to an ip version 6 address

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I am quite new with codeigniter and ion-auth2 package for authentications. right now I have my codeigniter and the ion-auth package, both are merged,database has set upped and looks to have no error. I can access my index.php and default page with no error, but when I want to go to my ion-auth route using it's route like this:

```
localhost:81/code/index.php/auth
```

after i press enter.it redirects me to a route like this:

```
[::1]/code/index.php/auth/login
```

My problem is why I am getting the IPv6 format after accessing the auth controller.

The page looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's just your localhost ip, when you deploy your project online it will be something like a ipv4 address, don't worry about it. It's okay and will impact no harm to your project :)

Comment: thank you but it shows to me a 404 page not found.
in above message i have uploaded the page snapshot you can check it please.

Comment: coz it's the not in your base_url, make your base_url dynamic and it will not show you 404.

just replace your base_url config value to these lines, and it will work like a charm

`$base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$base_url .= "://". @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .=     str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;`

Answer (score 0):

You could update your Apache/Nguni settings to respond to this as well but the easiest solution is probably to set your base_url in your codeigniter config file you “local host” or whatever you’re using for the v4.